Passing Audio From Server To Frontend
I have a web application running in node. I am web scraping data on my backend and want to be able to grab audio files from a third party and pass them to my client.
I am using the fetch-cookie npm library to fake a login to my third party site and then make the request for the audio file. When making this request in the browser (with the correct cookies) it will return the file and is playable in the browser.
The URL looks like: https://uswest2.calabriocloud.com/api/rest/recording/media/play/{audioID}?type=webma
My backend looks like:
module.exports.getAudio = async function(req, res, next) {
  const audioID = req.query.audioID;

  // code here to setup and make the login request to set my cookies

  fetchCookie('https://uswest2.calabriocloud.com/api/rest/recording/media/play/' + audioID + '?type=webma', requestOptions)
    .then((res) => res.blob())
    .then(async (myBlob) => {
      console.log(myBlob); // logs: "Blob { size: 7006, type: 'audio/webm;charset=utf-8' }"

      res.type(myBlob.type)
      myBlob.arrayBuffer().then((buf) => {
        res.send(Buffer.from(buf))
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error fetching audio:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Error fetching audio');
    });
}

getAudio is handling my /audio route. Making this request from my frontend I can see that some data is being sent.
My frontend looks like:
const response = await fetch('/audio?audioID=' + audioID);
const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
console.dir(arrayBuffer);

var blb = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'audio/webm' });
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blb);
console.log(blobUrl);
const audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = blobUrl;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
audio.play();

Logging my array buffer shows that I have data: ArrayBuffer(7006) however I cannot get any audio to play. Additionally audio.play() creates the error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

I am sure that I'm missing something. How can I get audio to play?
I have tried calling localhost:3000/audio?audioID=12341 from my browser and it seems to make the media request and creates the default media player in chrome but isn't able to be played.
